# Xcode debugs from bottom to top direction

Tags: macos, debugging, xcode5

I am facing a very strange problem with Xcode. Naturally Xcode debugs lines from top to bottom direction, but in my case Xcode steps through source from Bottom to Top.

You may find its video here,

[Youtube Video](http://youtu.be/3NaBESos0Hc)

I tried to solve it by

```
-Restarting Xcode 
-Deleting derived data
-Resetting simulator
-Restarting mac
```

Still the same.

Kindly Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Those who can't understand the question are requested to see the video , put below the question.

Comment: Is this an optimized build? The compiler can rearrange the instructions so long as it doesn't change the output of your program. That can cause the debugger to jump around as you're seeing, since the instructions aren't executed in the order you wrote them.

Comment: In fact i don't know how to optimise the build so this is not an optimised build.

Comment: As user1118321 has said, the optimizer can cause instructions that cause the debugger to appear to execute out of order. Not knowing how to use the optimizer does not mean that you are not running an optimized build. Your Xcode settings may have it on by default if you're doing any type of release build. And not knowing how to turn on the optimizer makes it that much more likely that your compiler settings are not configured the way you think that they are.

I would post a screenshot of your "Build Settings" filtered for "Optimization Level".

Comment:  - Same problem aavyo..

Comment: kyarek kyarek Xcode y upgrade karta jao :P